# Solution to Nielsen & Chuang Exercise 5.3 (FFT)

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, quantum-fourier-transform

Can somebody help me with the solution of Nielsen Chuang, where we are supposed to derive the FFT from the equation (5.4):

$$|j_1,\ldots,j_n\rangle\rightarrow\frac{\big(|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i 0.j_n}|1\rangle\big)\big(|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i 0.j_{n-1}j_n}|1\rangle\big)\cdots \big(|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i 0.j_1j_2\cdots j_n}|1\rangle\big)}{2^{n/2}}.\tag{5.4}$$

I know that I have to somehow split it into even and odd parts to get the FFT, but I don't see how exactly I am supposed to do that.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: please have a look at https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation to see how to format math on the site

Comment: isn't the explanation given explicitly in the text? Cna you be more specific on what you find unclear about it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a homework question so I will not give full details.

---

First, the question asks to show that a straightforward application of DFT takes  $\Theta(2^{2n})$ operations on an input with $2^n$ components. This is quite easy to see if we look at the $2^n \times 2^n = 2^{2n}$ matrix of DFT:
$$
W = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}} \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&\cdots &1 \\
1&\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3&\cdots&\omega^{2^n-1} \\
1&\omega^2&\omega^4&\omega^6&\cdots&\omega^{2(2^n-1)}\\ 1&\omega^3&\omega^6&\omega^9&\cdots&\omega^{3(2^n-1)}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&\omega^{2^n-1}&\omega^{2(2^n-1)}&\omega^{3(2^n-1)}&\cdots&\omega^{(2^n-1)(2^n-1)}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If we multiply $W$ with a vector and count the operations we get the result.

---

Now, how can we cut down the operation count using equation (5.4)?

Equation (5.4) allows you to take advantage of the fact that the Fourier transformed $|j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_n\rangle$ is made out of $n$ tensored $2\times 1$ vectors. So, we process each $2\times 1$ vector independently by performing the following $n$ mappings:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle) &\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + e^{2\pi i 0.j_n}|1\rangle),\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle) &\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + e^{2\pi i 0.j_1 \ldots j_n}|1\rangle).
\end{align}
Each mapping takes a constant number of operations in $n$ as it is simply multiplying a $2 \times 1$ vector by a $2\times 2$ phase matrix. I believe in the book the matrix is as follows:
$$
R_k = \begin{pmatrix}
1 && 0\\
0 && e^{2 \pi i /2^k}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Hence, we perform $n$ matrix-vector multiplication to process a single $|j_1\ldots j_n\rangle$.

We know that an arbitrary vector $|\psi\rangle$ on $n$ qubits can be written as a linear combination of $2^n$ binary kets $|j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_n\rangle$. For example, for $n=2$, an arbitrary state can be written as
a linear combination of $2^2$ binary kets like so
$$
|\psi\rangle = a |00\rangle + b|01\rangle +c|10\rangle+d|11\rangle.
$$

Therefore, to transform $|\psi\rangle$ on $n$ qubits, we need to process $2^n$ binary vectors $|j_1, \ldots j_n\rangle$ by performing $n$ mappings described above. Since each such binary vector requires $n$ matrix-vector multiplications, and there are $2^n$ of them, it takes $\Theta(n 2^n)$ operations.